# Application is not working on lock screen

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

My application works on the lock screen of all phones, but not on the lock screen of xiaomi phones. I added the following to my code, but it still doesn't work.

```
private void addFlags() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    //show lock screen
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (keyguardManager != null)
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be due to Miui battery saver. If you have any of Xiaomi devices, try setting in  application settings Battery saver to "No restrictions".

Comment: The "Show on lock screen" option in the phone settings is deactivated.